# How do I use jquery to get data from a form before submission?

Tags: php, jquery, gravityforms

I am trying to get data from a gravity forms field to update data in another field.  From my research it seems I need to use jquery to do this.  What is the bast way to handle this? If I put the following code in my php code - how do I access the variable?

```
add_filter("gform_field_value_MgrPhone", "set_mgr_phone");
function set_mgr_phone($value){
   global $wpdb; 
   $mgr_name = "Tracy Kaufenberg";
   ?>
  <script>
    var mgr_name = document.getElementById('input_20_81').value;
    console.log(document.getElementById('input_20_81').value);
  </script>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT PhoneNumber 
        FROM ADusers 
        WHERE phoneNumber IS NOT NULL AND displayName = '" . mgr_name2 . "'" ;

//echo $sql;
$sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql,20);
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
$myArray = array();
//echo count($myArray);
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $myArray[] = $result->PhoneNumber;
}

foreach ($myArray as $v) {
    $phone = $v;
}
echo $phone;
return $phone;
```

}

Comment: Are you asking how to access the variable in javascript or php?

Comment: You can use JavaScript. jQuery is a Framework for JavaScript; so JS will work natively and jQuery needs a library loaded. Remember that PHP is only executed Server side and JS/jQuery is Client Side. You can pull the `value` from a form element in JS/jQuery. The code you posted will work on the client if jQuery is loaded.

Comment: I am asking how to use the variable mgr_name in php. @Twisty

Comment: I updated the code to show yo what I am trying to do.  This works with $mgr_name but I want to use the variable from the javascript.  How do I do that>

Comment: @TKaufeberg the is no easy way to do that directly. You must use Ajax to send the data back to PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Native JavaScript option:

```
<script>
  var mgr_name = document.getElementById('input_20_81').value;
</script>
```

You can test this in your JavaScript console too:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('input_20_81').value);
```

I would strongly suggest you take a basic JavaScript Tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

You can then look at jQuery if you want.

**Update**

Moving a PHP Variable into JavaScript

```
<?php
$mgr_name = "Tracy Kaufenberg";
echo "<script>var mgr_name = '$mgr_name';</script>";
?>
```

Since PHP is a preprocessor, it is only executed on the server-side. So to pass a variable back to PHP, we have to send it via HTTP with either GET or POST.

```
<html>
<body>
  <form action="saveMgrName.php" method="POST">
    Manager Name <input type="text" id="input_20_81" name="input_20_81" value="Tracy Kaufenberg" />
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So the user hits `Send` and the browser sends the data to the web server and PHP can access it using `$_POST['input_20_81']` and the value will be `"Tracy Kaufenberg"`.

If you want to collect data from PHP with data entered in the Browser, you can use AJAX to send that data to PHP and get a response without loading a new page. It uses JavaScript to build a HTTP Request and send it to the server *in the background* in a sense.

Given the above HTML Code, you can use jQuery like so to accomplish this.

```
$(function(){
  $("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), { mgr_name: $("#input_20_81").val() }, function(response){
      console.log(response);
      if(response){
        alert("Manager Name is saved.");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

If you need to GET data from PHP, you may consider using `$.get()` versus `$.post()`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I like that you suggested for taking a basic JavaScript Tutorial. :)

Comment: I did take the tutorial on JavaScript and JQuery but I am still stuck.  I updated the code to show what I am trying to accomplish.  The code works for the hardcoded $mgr_name but I want to use the variable from the javascript.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: @TKaufeberg updated with a small AJAX example. It's still not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish, yet this may help you.